# Inverse Laplace test question

Tags: laplace-transform

I had a test yesterday and couldn't figure out the answer to this question.  Was wondering if someone could walk me through the solution.
$$\dfrac{(13s+3)}{(s^2+2s+5)}$$

I figured I had to complete the square in the denominator then split the fraction up into 
$$\dfrac{13s}{(s+1)^2+4} + \dfrac3{(s+1)^2+4}$$

That would allow me to solve the second fraction as $3/2 \exp(-t) \sin(2t)$.

I couldn't figure how to solve for the first fraction unless I shouldn't have split them up at all.

So what is the proper way to solve it?

Comment: The first fraction will transform into a $\cos ()$ term.

Comment: hint: $13s+3=13(s+1)-10$

Comment: you can use the [model solution](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Laplace_transform#Example_4:_Mixing_sines.2C_cosines.2C_and_exponentials) and just plug in the constants

Comment: Hmmm...13e^(-t) x cos(2t) - 5e^(-t) x sin(2t) ????

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you noticed that you needed to complete the square in the denominator, let that dictate the form of the new, preferred numerator as follows:
$$
{13s+3\over s^2+2s+5}={13s+3\over (s+1)^2+2^2}={A\color{blue}{(s+1)}+B\cdot \color{red}{2}\over \color{blue}{(s+1)}^2+\color{red}{2}^2},
$$
where equating coefficients between the first and last versions of the numerator yields $A=13$, $B=-5$.

This last form is quite helpful since a standard table of Laplace transforms shows
\begin{align}
\mathscr{L}\left\{e^{-at}\cos(bt)\right\}={s+a\over (s+a)^2+b^2},\\
\mathscr{L}\left\{e^{-at}\sin(bt)\right\}={b\over (s+a)^2+b^2},
\end{align}
so
\begin{align}
\mathscr{L}^{-1}\left\{{13s+3\over s^2+2s+5}\right\}&=\mathscr{L}^{-1}\left\{{A(s+1)+B\cdot 2\over (s+1)^2+2^2}\right\}\\
&=A\,\mathscr{L}^{-1}\left\{{s+1\over (s+1)^2+2^2}\right\}+B\,\mathscr{L}^{-1}\left\{{2\over (s+1)^2+2^2}\right\}\\
&=Ae^{-t}\cos(2t)+Be^{-t}\sin(2t),\\
&=13e^{-t}\cos(2t)-5e^{-t}\sin(2t).
\end{align}